# What are websocket clients available for Android?

Tags: java, android, websocket

I have implemented a prototype for Java based chat application. It uses jetty client and tomcat 8 server for websocket communication. I wanted to port the client to android. I am not sure Jetty is the best fit for android environment since I am getting errors like the following while I run the app:

```
12-18 23:43:59.016    2315-2315/com.example.root.chat_application I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger>
12-18 23:43:59.016    2315-2315/com.example.root.chat_application I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger>
12-18 23:43:59.032    2315-2315/com.example.root.chat_application W/System.err﹕ Defaulting Uptime to NOIMPL due to (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException) Implementation not available
```

Please suggest on options available for websocket clients for android.
Thanks.

Comment: there is this one : https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket (see http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps)

Comment: For the logging errors, this fixed this issue:

            `System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class",  "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog")`

Answer (score 2):

There is a port of Jetty 8 Client available here: https://github.com/knowledgecode/jetty-websocket-android. I haven't tested it yet, but you can have a look at it.

Other Web-Socket client implementations which seem to work on Android as well are:

- https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket
- https://github.com/palmerc/SecureWebSockets